# While loop in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a case where I require to perform a set of operations in Apache Spark until a condition is met.

The most intuitive way for a serial implementation seems to be a while loop, however for some reason it does not feel right for Spark.

What essentially I am doing is this Clustering data. As an input I have an rdd of object that is represented only by its id, count of neighbours, list of tuples with neioghbour id and the count of neighbours the neighbour has .

RDD:
(item_id, nbr_count, [,..])
(item_id2, nbr_count, [,..])

In a loop i need to:
In a map function I require to select the the neighbour having the highest nbr_count in each item. Or if the item nbr_count is greater than any neighbour count, I select the item_Id. We will call this item group (with the group being the item id with the highest nbr_count)

Filter those rows having item_id == item_group. Collect their neighbours and broadcast them. Then remove all rows having item_id that are presented in the broadcasted list.

Restart the loop - with the map function (to assign item_group) ignoring any  that exists in the broadcasted list.

The termination condition should be, when the remaining items all have an item group that is the same item_id. However this condition is a little difficult because I would require an additional collect apart from the one I already do, therefore I can update the code and condition .. such that when I collect the neighbours that I will remove, I collect only the new ones for this iteration.

I know this is a little complex. My question is mainly how to deal with while loops, how do I synchronise the condition among all nodes, using a broadcast variable?

And may be there some indeterministic behaviour with while loops?

```
while broadcast_rdd.count() == 0:
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : assign_item_group(x))
    rdd_filtered = rdd.filter(lambda item_id,neighbours, item_group: item_id == item_group).map(lambda item_id,neighbours, item_group: neighbours)

    rdd_filtered.collect()
    broadcast_rdd = sc.broadcast(rdd_filtered)
    rdd = rdd.filter(lambda item_id,neighbours, item_group: item_id not in broadcast_rdd)
```

Is their a 'spark' way of doing this, and does the while loop make sense ?

Comment: you will have to explain your condition more elaborately. and if possible give sample input and expected output too

Comment: JCassar, in order to tell whether your code make sense more details are required.
Although loops are avoided usually in Spark processing, sometimes you can't run away from it I guess. Can you share more details? What is CONDITION? what is it your trying to do?

Comment: Can't say I follow, but I have KPI generation for a DWH with Hadoop and use while loops running driver only. Now I may as well have done that with SCALA JDBC or ORACLE and sqooped the results. That is possible due to lower volumes, but here u r right, does it fit the SPARK paradigm? Interested to see how you resolve this.

Comment: Interesting to hear a solution to this or how the op has solved this